# How merge many documents into one using MongoDB's Java Driver?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm working with documents that contain music playlists.

Each document has this structure:

```
{
    "user_id": "5858",
    "playlists": [
        {
            "name": "My Playlist",
            "guild_ids": ["7575"],
            "items": [
                {
                     "title": "title",
                     "url": "url",
                     "duration": 200000
                } 
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to extract all playlists from the same guild.
But the thing is that i'd like the results to be returned in a single document. One single document with a list of playlists.

The expected result for guild_id=5656 would be like this:

```
{
    "playlists": [
        {
            "name": "My Playlist",
            "guild_ids": ["5656"],
            "items": [
                {
                     "title": "title",
                     "url": "url",
                     "duration": 200000
                } 
            ]
        },
        // other playlists where guild_ids contains "5656"
    ]
}
```

I tried to use aggregation but i always get the same number of documents as the number of unique user_ids. I get the playlists grouped by user_id.

Comment: Please post some more data and your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind:"$playlists"
    },
    {
        $match:{
            "playlists.guild_ids":{
                $in:["7575"]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":null,
            "playlists":{
               $push: "$playlists"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5d88225e38db7cf8d3f75cd6"),
  "user_id" : "5858",
  "playlists" : [
    {
      "name" : "My Playlist",
      "guild_ids" : [
        "7575"
      ],
      "items" : [
        {
          "title" : "title",
          "url" : "url",
          "duration" : 200000
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5d88225e38db7cf8d3f75cd7"),
  "user_id" : "5858",
  "playlists" : [
    {
      "name" : "My Playlist 2",
      "guild_ids" : [
        "1234"
      ],
      "items" : [
        {
          "title" : "title",
          "url" : "url",
          "duration" : 200000
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5d88225e38db7cf8d3f75cd8"),
  "user_id" : "5858",
  "playlists" : [
    {
      "name" : "My Playlist 3",
      "guild_ids" : [
        "7575"
      ],
      "items" : [
        {
          "title" : "title",
          "url" : "url",
          "duration" : 200000
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "playlists" : [
        {
            "name" : "My Playlist",
            "guild_ids" : [
                "7575"
            ],
            "items" : [
                {
                    "title" : "title",
                    "url" : "url",
                    "duration" : 200000
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "My Playlist 3",
            "guild_ids" : [
                "7575"
            ],
            "items" : [
                {
                    "title" : "title",
                    "url" : "url",
                    "duration" : 200000
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Query analysis:** We are unwinding the `playlists`, filtering only those which has `7575` guild ID and then grouping them all again.